# how my knockout.js model should be?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a dropdown that selects type of car. Each car has different input fields so I would like to display only the fields that related to the selected car. Here is some code:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">car 1</option>
    <option value="2">car 2</option>
    <option value="3">car 3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div id="car1Fields">
    <input type="text" id="car1field1" />
    <input type="text" id="car1field2" />
</div>
<div id="car2Fields">
    <input type="text" id="car2field1" />
    <input type="text" id="car2field2" />
    <input type="text" id="car2field3" />
</div>
<div id="car3Fields">
    <input type="text" id="car3field1" />
</div>
```

I am using knockout.js and I don't know how exactly the model or models should look like.
Should I have model for each car type or one model for all the structure?
How can I control the visibility of the fields using the models (when car 2 selected I don't want to display car1Fields)?

Comment: Do you really have different properties for each car? Or properties the same but you don't want to show some of them for some of the cars?

Comment: I have completely different properties for each car. There are also 2 or 3 properties that appears in each car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single model for all car types. Just add `car type` property to it:

```
function Car(type)
{
    var self = this;   

    self.carType = ko.observable(type);

    self.car1field1 = ko.observable("car1field1");
    self.car1field2 = ko.observable("car1field2");

    self.car2field1 = ko.observable("car2field1");
    self.car2field2 = ko.observable("car2field2");    
    self.car2field3 = ko.observable("car2field3");

    self.car3field1 = ko.observable("car3field1");
}
```

For controlling visibility of `divs` you can use either `If` or `Visible` binding:

```
<div data-bind="if: carType() == 'Car 1'" id="car1Fields">
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/66AAY/

Comment: What about the server side? Should I create a class that contains all the members of all cars?

Comment: It's up to you. You can have the same structure on server or different. But if you choose the different structure on server I will have to map it to existing javascript view models.